# How to post open graph story to test users that is automatically created for open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've created an app on Facebook and I would like to publish an open graph to the test users account that is automatically created for you. But I'm not quite sure how to do this. If I click to use that user and try to go to the graph api it says test users are not allowed?

So how do I publish an open graph story to a test account?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? You should be posting the actions using your own app that you developed, while logged into your app as the Open Graph Test User - not using the Graph API Explorer tool

Comment: I've been using the tool. I see I should use the app instead. I will give this a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a test user on your **app**
2. Link the user's facebook account to Open Graph User
3. Perform actions in your app to generate stories
4. DONE!